Temp Inside a Procedure in Pgadmin 4 (Postgres) version 8.4 and return the temp table to called program
I am trying to create and populate a temp table inside a procedure to save some intermediate state of the data. Please see the example code.
CREATE or replace procedure sp_getOfficeStateData (
    inout  PROCESSING_DATE_YMD          CHAR(06),                                         
    inout  TYPE_OF_RUN                  VARCHAR (1))          
    
RETURNS TABLE(
        STATES_WITHIN_OFFI_SF_DISION VARCHAR (3), 
        STATES_WITHIN_MIS_ST_P_UNIT VARCHAR(3),
        STATES_WITHIN_PROCESSING_UNIT  VARCHAR (2), 
        STATES_WITHIN_STATE_INITIALS      VARCHAR (2),               
        STATES_WITHIN_GEOGRAPHIC_STATE    VARCHAR (2),               
        STATES_WITHIN_ALPH_ORDER_STATE_NO VARCHAR (2)                          
        )  
as
$$
DECLARE
begin
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ALL_OF_THE_OFF_OR_ST_DATA(
        STATES_WITHIN_OFFI_SF_DISION VARCHAR (3), 
        STATES_WITHIN_MIS_ST_P_UNIT VARCHAR(3),
        STATES_WITHIN_PROCESSING_UNIT VARCHAR (2),  
        STATES_WITHIN_STATE_INITIALS      VARCHAR (2),               
        STATES_WITHIN_GEOGRAPHIC_STATE    VARCHAR (2),               
        STATES_WITHIN_ALPH_ORDER_STATE_NO VARCHAR (2)               
                     
            ) ON COMMIT DROP;
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM ALL_OF_THE_OFF_OR_ST_DATA;
end;
$$
language 
plpgsql;

Please help me with this. When trying to create this Stored Procedure the database returns this error message: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TABLE"
LINE 41:     RETURNS TABLE(STATES_WITHIN_OFFI_SF_DISION VARCHAR (3), ...
^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 2327

Please tell me you are not actually using Postgres 8.4 as per Versioning it is 10 years past EOL.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Procedures didn't exist in version 8.4. Upgrade to version 16 or something else that is supported.

I don't understand the mix of inout and returning a table either.

I am trying to return output fields as well as temp tables to the calling metho. these inout fields and tables will be populated in this stored procedure.


You need to make clear what version of Postgres you are working with. 2) Procedures don't have a return value, read Returning from procedure.

